# Android on Blackberry: How to Play Videos

Tags: android, video, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

i've ported some Apps from Android to Blackberry (by repacking them with the Blackberry tools). Most of the App seems to work fine, however i con not get the Videos to work.
The Loading indicator appears (but does not spin). Nothing else Happens (No Exceptions or anything on the LogCat or Console. After I while i get the Dialog which ask me if i want to shut down the App as it is not reacting.

Has anybody ever managed to Play Videos using the Android API on Blackberry 10?
Are there any tricks to use? Like just using special Video Formats or anything else i need to know?

Comment: You may find the video is unsupported. Probably a silly question, but have you tried playing the video using the built in video player?

Comment: If you can wait 2 weeks for the next release of the bbndk, I think, concerning specifcally Videos or Webviews, that you should.

Comment: I found out: mp4 seems to be working. Playing m3u8 streams doesn't (which isn't very surprising, considering blackberry android runtime is based upon android 2.3.3). At the moment i am waiting for an offical statement from blackberry support and will let you know if i have got an offical answer

Comment: The LogCat says: 
`11-19 13:08:50.389: E/MediaPlayer(19742936): error (1, 1)`
`11-19 13:10:10.705: W/MediaPlayer(19742936): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have Feedback from RIM. Some Networkprotocols are not supported for Video(streaming):
http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_network_protocols.html . And some more Bad News: They also say "it will also not be supported with the final OS-update at launch".

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in the simulator, there are no codecs present there.

Comment: actually i have an Blackberry 10 dev beta phone